# Scriptella: XML to DB: Insert Into from XPATH

Tags: scriptella

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<XML>
  <Table name='test'>
    <Row>
      <Field name='key'>1000</Field>
      <Field name='text'>Test</Field>
    </Row>
  </Table>
</XML>
```

id like to parse this xml and use it within an insert statement:

```
<query  connection-id="in">
    /XML/Table/Row

    <script connection-id="out">
        INSERT INTO X t (
                t.entitykey, 
                t.text
             )
             VALUES 
             (
                 ????????
             );

    </script>
</query>
```

How do I access a specific Field-Tag from within the insert statement using XPATH?
We prefer to have one XSD that takes all table layouts into account and not to maintain n xsd for each table hence the Field[@name] design.

Thanks
Matthias

Answer (score 2):

[Xpath driver](http://scriptella.javaforge.com/docs/api/scriptella/driver/xpath/package-summary.html#package_description) exposes a variable called [`node`](http://scriptella.javaforge.com/docs/api/scriptella/driver/xpath/NodeVariable.html) which provides a context for executing xpath expressions over a currently returned node. You can use the following expression to get the value of a particular field:

```
<script connection-id="out">
    INSERT INTO X t (t.entitykey, t.text)
         VALUES ( ?{node.getString("./Field[@name = 'text']")} );
</script>
```