# Convert XML to CSV with Scriptella, how to get attribute values?

Tags: xml, csv, scriptella

I found an example of converting XML to CSV,In the example used, this structure

```
<!-- Demo input for ETL -->
<CATALOG>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
    </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

In this file structure,  Scriptella code:

```
<script connection-id="out">Title;Artist;Country;Company;Price;Year</script>
<query connection-id="in">
    <!--XPath which all CD elements in a catalog-->
    /CATALOG/CD
    <!--Outputs all matched elements-->
    <script connection-id="out" if="rownum>1">$TITLE;$ARTIST;$COUNTRY;$COMPANY;$PRICE;$YEAR</script>
</script>
```

How can I convert the XML file that has the following structure

```
<CATALOG>
    <CD title='Empire Burlesque' artist='Bob Dylan'  country='USA'/>
    .............
    <CD title='Empire Burlesque' artist='Bob Dylan'  country='USA'/>
</CATALOG>
```

How do I get to the values of attributes in XML?

Comment: Look [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486352/scriptella-xml-to-db-insert-into-from-xpath), the answer suggests that you can use a special [`node` variable](http://scriptella.javaforge.com/docs/api/scriptella/driver/xpath/NodeVariable.html) like so: `?{node.getString("./@title")}`. I don't have Scriptella so I can't write a tested answer, but are welcome to post a quick answer of your own once you figured out how to integrate that in your output script, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You need first to have properly described drivers for all your connections. You cannot parse XML with Scriptella unless you use the xpath driver. More information there: http://scriptella.org/reference/drivers.html

Now for the magic bits:
- you could use java libraries as alternate possibilities but since these 2 drivers are supported out of the box, I suggest to go with them
- you wish to import xml -> xpath driver is needed
- you wish to export csv -> csv driver is needed
- text driver can also be used for outputting csv data, but you'd have to handle quoting and separators manually

If your xml data is in file `data.xml` and you wish to export it as csv data in file `data.csv`, I would suggest using the following scriptella etl script:

```
<!DOCTYPE etl SYSTEM "http://scriptella.javaforge.com/dtd/etl.dtd">
<etl>
  <connection id="in" driver="xpath" url="data.xml" />
  <connection id="out" driver="csv" url="data.csv">
    quote=
    separator=;
  </connection>
  <script connection-id="out">
    TITLE,ARTIST,COUNTRY,COMPANY,PRICE,YEAR
  </script>
  <query connection-id="in">
    /CATALOG/CD
    <script connection-id="out">
      $TITLE,$ARTIST,$COUNTRY,$COMPANY,$PRICE,$YEAR
    </script>
  </query>
</etl>
```

Please respect the case used inside XML source. You must use `$TITLE` and not `$title` nor `$Title`, since `<TITLE>` is present in your XML source.

The rownum test is not needed for such ETL task.

Answer (score 0):

You access attributes by name, just the same as tags. Look at [here](https://scriptella.org/docs/api/scriptella/driver/xpath/package-summary.html#package_description)

In your case, setting the node to CD by xpath /CATALOG/CD you can access Tag and attributes this way:

```
$CD      -> ''     (because CD is an emtpy tag)
$title   -> 'Empire Burlesque' 
$artist  -> 'Bob Dylan' 
$country -> 'USA'
```

Also you can access other elements not in current selected node using function node.getString() and xpath like:

```
${node.getString("../CATALOG")}
```

With this functions you can access elements (tags) by path and attributes by bracket-at notation like:

```
${node.getString("../CATALOG/CD[@title='Empire Burlesque']")}
```

you can also use index to select elements in the set rather than attributes:

```
${node.getString("../CATALOG/CD[2]")}
```

this index notation is valid when using variables like in:

```
xml file: <A><B>1</B><B>2</B><B>3</B></A>
in scriptella:
/A
${B[2]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<CATALOG>
    <CD title='Empire Burlesque' artist='Bob Dylan'  country='USA'/>
    .............
    <CD title='Empire Burlesque' artist='Bob Dylan'  country='USA'/>
</CATALOG>
```

You can get to the values of attributes in XML by this example:

```
/CATALOG/CD[1]/@title
```